# Cannot define the most basic object in R

Tags: r

This is really simple stuff, why is it not working?

Script window:

```
x <- 8  
y <- 5  
x + y
```

Console:

```
> x + y  
Error: object 'x' not found
```

Even if I get rid of y and just input x I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the third line after (not before) running the first two?

Comment: @RichScriven Yes, I went way beyond that. Have a look at my comment to DTYK.

Comment: @Renu Yea, that's the script copied directly from R, I was using RStudio but I tried standalone R to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

So, this was far more simple than I was approaching it. I missed it completely and I'm sure they showed us in the tut, but I was looking at someone else's laptop. It was simply the method I was using to execute the script. My script was fine. I didn't realize just running it would only send the last line. The issue is in the way R deals with multiple lines. Basically you need to let it know by highlighting the script then running it - I'm not sure why this is, there must be a reason.

Where I finally found out: [Editing and Executing Code](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484448-Editing-and-Executing-Code) straight from the RStudio support website.

Even the support at Uni were treating it with far more complexity than necessary...remote support. If I went in they would have realized I was a complete idiot and set me straight right away. Time wasted I could have spent studying, or you know, normal life stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could try restarting R. Also, do note that variable names are case-sensitive

Comment: I restarted, uninstalled and then reinstalled a different version and then in my frustration did a completely clean install of Windows 10 (not the reset method). What I have written above is the exact script I ran, so I'm pretty sure it wasn't a syntax error. I have literally copied and pasted it directly from the script window. This is really stressing me out because it's crucial for the statistics class I'm taking for my masters. Is there a possibility of it being hardware? I really can't think of anything else.

Comment: Hmm... I can think of a few more things you could try. Try class(x) and class(y) to check whether you are really adding together 2 numeric variables. Verify that you have used <- as an assignment sign rather than <=